# How to limit an Associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array like follow

```
Array ( [1274] => 2 [2700] => 3 [2701] => 4 [2702] => 2 [2699] => 2 [2698] => 1 [2694] => 1......)
```

what i want is to take the first 10 elements from this array. I Used `array_slice`. But then the new array will be like

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 2 [4] => 2 [5] => 1 [6] => 1.....)
```

It limits the array but array keys have been removed.
How can i get the keys as well? Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
$slice = array_intersect_key($whole,array_flip(array_slice(array_keys($whole),0,10)));
```

If you want something more readable, this'll work:

```
$keys = array_keys($whole);
$slice = Array();
$firstkeys = array_slice($keys,0,10);
foreach($firstkeys as $key) $slice[$key] = $whole[$key];
```

Comment: Wowww Thanks buddy i have gone through lots of pages to find an answer.This works Perfect.Thank you very much..I will accept your answer as soon as i can.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I love one-liners XD

Answer (score 2):

You can limit an iteration on the array and convert it back to an array:

```
$first = iterator_to_array(new LimitIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), 0, 10));
```

[Demo](http://eval.in/12076)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$res    = array_chunk($array,10,true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res[0]);
```

If you want to know the second set of 10 just `print_r($res[1]);`